# Estimating the bound of the integral over whole $\mathbb{R}$ of the Taylor remainder term?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-series

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function which has a smooth inverse and satisfies the estimate
\begin{equation}
\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert.
\end{equation}

Also, let $d\mu$ be the standard normal Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Assume that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f(x) -f(y) \rvert^2 d\mu(x) d\mu(y) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert x-y \rvert^2 d\mu(x) d\mu(y)
\end{equation}
as well.

Now, if we taylor-expand $f(x)$ around some fixed $w \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{equation}
f(x)-f(w)=f'(w)(x-w)+F(x,w)
\end{equation}

Here, the remainder term $F(x,w)$ satisfies the decay $o(\lvert x-w \rvert)$ when $\lvert x-y \rvert \to 0^+$. However, I wonder if there is any bound over
\begin{equation}
\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert F(x,w)-F(y,w) \rvert^2 d\mu(x)d\mu(y)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert x-y \rvert^2 d\mu(x)d\mu(y)}
\end{equation}
with respect to quantities regarding $f$ at $w$

This seems to be related to the behavior of $F(x,w)$ at $x$ far away from $w$, but I cannot figure out such behaviors..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I think you cannot get any finite bound in such generality. Do you have any other conditions on $f$?

Comment: Even if $f$ has a smooth inverse and $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert$? Moreover, $d\mu$ is a Gaussian measure. Still I can't do anything?

Comment: Yes, with all these conditions. If you do not have any other conditions on $f$, I can try to show that you cannot get any finite bound in such generality. Just let me know.

Comment: OK, I added another condition. I dearly hope it makes ssome difference.....

Comment: You have $|F(x,w) - F(y,w)| = |f(x) - f(y) + f'(w)(y-x)|$ by definition. So you can just apply triangle inequality to get the pointwise bound $$ |F(x,w) - F(y,w)|^2 \leq 2 (|f(x) - f(y)|^2 + |f'(w)|^2|x-y|^2) $$ from here on you can probably take over...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$We want to bound the ratio
\begin{equation*}
    R:=\frac ND,  
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    N:=\iint_{\R^2}(F(x,w)-F(y,w))^2 \mu(dx)\mu(dy),\quad 
    D:=\iint_{\R^2}(x-y)^2 \mu(dx)\mu(dy). 
\end{equation*}

We have $D=2$. Next,
\begin{equation*}
    A:=(F(x,w)-F(y,w))^2=(f(x)-f(y)-f'(w)(x-y))^2 \\ 
    \le2(f(x)-f(y))^2+2f'(w)^2(x-y)^2 
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    R=\frac N2&\le\iint_{\R^2}(f(x)-f(y))^2 \mu(dx)\mu(dy) \\ 
    &+f'(w)^2\iint_{\R^2}(x-y)^2 \mu(dx)\mu(dy) \\ 
    &\le(1+f'(w)^2)\iint_{\R^2}(x-y)^2 \mu(dx)\mu(dy)
    =2(1+f'(w)^2). 
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}

On the other hand,
\begin{equation*}
    A\ge\frac12\,f'(w)^2(x-y)^2-(f(x)-f(y))^2  
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}
    R=\frac N2\ge\frac14\,f'(w)^2\iint_{\R^2}(x-y)^2 \mu(dx)\mu(dy) \\ 
    -\frac12\,\iint_{\R^2}(x-y)^2 \mu(dx)\mu(dy)
    = \frac12\,f'(w)^2-1. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}

Thus, we have the upper bound on $R$ in \eqref{1} in terms of $|f'(w)|$. However, \eqref{2} shows that, if we cannot control $|f'(w)|$, then there is no finite bound on $R$.